# how to disable nested logic app from parent logic app or how to disable specific task from logic app

Tags: azure, nested, azure-logic-apps

I have parent logic app which calls various nested logic apps. I am doing parallel processing of those nested logic app calls. I want to disable one of the logic app from parent logic app. How do I disable the nested logic app from parent logic app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable one logic app in other logic app, you could use this action: [Invoke resource operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/arm/#invoke-resource-operation).

Actually it does the REST action, so you could refer to the below action setting set the action name to disable the it will disable the flow.

[image]

Comment: But since this task is in preview mode operation it is not going to work in Production environment. Am I correct?  Is there any other solution?